# Magnific Popup Gallery: How can I display a counter in an inline type item?

Tags: magnific-popup

I am using [magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) to display a mixed gallery of [image type](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#image_type) and [inline type](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#inline_type) items.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="magnific">Image Popup</a>

<a href="#test-popup" class="magnific mfp-inline">Show inline popup</a>

<!-- the inline content -->
<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
  Inline content
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.magnific').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image',
  gallery: {enabled: true}
});
```

The full working example is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mHpCx).

As you can see, the image type items automatically get a "x of y " counter like this:

[image]

How can I get this counter for inline type items, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work using *non-dynamically generated* inline items containing

`<div class="mfp-content"></div>`

patching magnific popup slightly:

https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/pull/537

Comment: I tried your code but still no counter. Did you add something to the inline markup ?

Answer (score 1):

It only can be added to dynamically generated inline popups, to do this you just need to add `<div class="mfp-content"></div>` to markup of item. Example http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/GpdFs

Otherwise, you'll need to write your own counter via popup API.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "popup API"?